# VSCode Coderunner issue

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, cygwin, vscode-code-runner

I was setting up a development environment(C) for a younger brother of mine in VS Code, I made the build.json and tasks.json and the code compiled and ran just fine. But its a lot of hassle for someone new to programming. I found an extension Code runner for the one click compile and run button. It worked just fine but I noticed the coderunner terminal which pops up is Output only and doesn't take any input. Googled and found out a simple fix to that is to make Code Runner use Bash. But it doesn't work at all anymore.

```
yudha@LAPTOP-PLIIOJAT /cygdrive/c/Users/yudha/OneDrive/Documents/C Projects/helloworld
$ cd "c:\Users\yudha\OneDrive\Documents\C Projects\helloworld\" && gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld && "c:\Users\yudha\OneDrive\Documents\C Projects\helloworld\"helloworld
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

this is the error which pops up every time now and I am pretty clueless. I am using the Cygwin bash as default terminal for VSCode with gcc

Comment: because you escape the closing quote to `cd`.  Backslashes aren't even required for path separators in Windows shell, I suggest always use forward slashes.

Comment: It is not me typing the command It is coderunner